# Copy Embedded Excel OLE Object in PPT

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to use VBA in PPT to open/edit embedded OLE excel objects, copy the selected cells, and then paste them back into the same slide. Is this even possible? I've gotten to the point of opening and editing the ole object but can't figure out how to copy the already selected cells. It needs to be the already selected cells as the data references are inconsistent and thus, cannot use static cell/sheet references. See below for my code thus far.

```
Dim slide As Object
Dim shape As Object
For Each slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each shape In slide.Shapes
        If shape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
            If InStr(shape.OLEFormat.ProgID, "Excel.Sheet") > 0 Then
                shape.OLEFormat.DoVerb (1) 
                '''shape.OLEFormat.Object.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:F20").Copy
                '''The above line works but I need the data reference to be dynamic.
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Sample file:
https://github.com/semajkim/Extract_PPT_Data/blob/c64c2aebe13eaa81501c35d20a3553281fc187c0/Example_PPT.pptm

Comment: Can you provide a download link for a mock presentation?

Comment: Sure, I just added a link to an example file I created. Not super familiar with GitHub just yet so lmk if you can't DL it.

Answer (score 0):

Note: There is no need to open the Workbooks.

`Range.CurrentRegion` will give you the dynamic range.

> ```
> Shape.OLEFormat.Object.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
> ```

Setting a reference to the `Microsoft Excel xx.x Object Library`.  This will allow you to type your variables, which enables Intellisense.

[image: VBAProject Reference Dialog]

```
Sub PasteRange()
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim Shape As Shape
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
        
    For Each Shape In ShapesWithWorkbooks
        Set Slide = Shape.Parent
        Set wb = Shape.OLEFormat.Object
            
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            ws.UsedRange.Copy
            Shape.Parent.Shapes.Paste
        Next
    Next
End Sub


Sub PrintWorkbooksWorksheetsUsedRanges()
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    For Each wb In ExtractExcelWorkbooks
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            Debug.Print wb.Name, ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
        Next
    Next
End Sub
    
Function ExtractExcelWorkbooks() As Collection
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim Shape As Shape
    For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
            If Shape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                If InStr(Shape.OLEFormat.ProgID, "Excel.Sheet") > 0 Then
                    Map.Add Shape.OLEFormat.Object
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set ExtractExcelWorkbooks = Map
End Function

Sub PrintSlidesShapesWorkbooksWorksheetsUsedRanges()
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim Shape As Shape
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    
    For Each Shape In ShapesWithWorkbooks
        Set Slide = Shape.Parent
        Set wb = Shape.OLEFormat.Object
        
        For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
            Debug.Print Slide.Name, Shape.Name, wb.Name, ws.Name, ws.UsedRange.Address
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function ShapesWithWorkbooks() As Collection
    Dim Map As New Collection
    Dim Slide As Slide
    Dim Shape As Shape
    For Each Slide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each Shape In Slide.Shapes
            If Shape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                If InStr(Shape.OLEFormat.ProgID, "Excel.Sheet") > 0 Then
                    Map.Add Shape
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Set ShapesWithWorkbooks = Map
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I have a couple of questions:
-You specify 'Worksheets(1)' but is there a way to make that dynamic as well?
-Not all of the data is guaranteed to have cell 'A1' included in it either. Is there a way to capture the dynamic range without using an 'anchor' cell?
-Why did you separate ExcelSheetShapes() as a separate function? Does that make the program faster?
-I should have specified this in the original post but how do I paste while applying 'Keep Source Formatting'? It looks like '.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetaFile' is what I'm looking for?

Comment: -Finally, are you able to use all the excel properties/methods in an embedded excel object via ppt vba? (e.g. your use of 'Range.CurrentRegion')

Comment: @James I would add a reference to Microsoft Excel Object Model and set the correct datatypes for the variables.  `.Worksheets(1).UsedRange` will reference all the used cells.  I don't think that there will ever be more than one worksheet.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your first sentence means? Which question is that addressing? Also, almost all of my embedded excel objects have several worksheets. This anomaly is present in the sample file I provided as well.

Comment: @James I expanded on my answer.

Comment: @James [Example_PPT.pptm Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C9Dcv7Erm9RUvayDHpQ-ufWPB_UZYOii/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thanks again, @TinMan. I've revised 'ws.UsedRange.Address' to 'wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange' in order to narrow the scope to the 1 worksheet. However, the table created sometimes includes cells/rows that are not displayed in the ppt slide. This occurs in slide 1 - see below for the revised ppt with the described anomaly.

https://mega.nz/file/4NwDWJha#LNyjDLBwKnYoCUN6zaYtncOhYTK__UI_XPhF7ZCzPHI

Is there something like 'ActiveSheet.DisplayedRange' that would capture just the range of cells that ppt displays on the slide?

Comment: @James Slide 2 shape 1,  `wb.Windows(1).VisibleRange` returns `$E$9:$Y$36` in the Presentation that you linked me.  `E9` is the top left cell.  You could use the shapes width and height to calculate the viewable range.  Make sure to set all your object variables to nothing.  If you get an error and the code will not run, go to task manager and shutdown all instances of excel.

Comment: 'Wb.Windows(1).VisibleRange' returns '$E$9:$AC$51' for me. Additionally, some data tables also have adjacent cells that include irrelevant data (Apologies, I did not simulate this in the sample file. I've added another slide to simulate this, see slide 3: https://mega.nz/file/pQ4jAYgL#C_Qxp-64a7sIpUciNzfnzE3hkwNbfzRs22twd8DssEI). Thus, neither 'wb.Windows(1).VisibleRange' and 'wb.ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Address' satisfy the projects requirement as the range resulted includes these irrelevant cells and the height and width of the shape would not be an accurate representation of the shape.

Comment: Also, I noticed that when you 'Edit' (as opposed to 'Open') the oleobject, excel is opened within ppt and only the data displayed is shown. There are black borders that can be used to expand the displayed information. See https://superuser.com/questions/188328/changing-bounds-of-excel-file-embedded-in-powerpoint for a relevant question regarding the borders/bounds of an embedded excel sheet; the top answer elaborates on how to manually adjust these bounds. The bounded range must be retrievable…right? If so, would you happen to know how? Thanks again for your patience, @TinMan.

Comment: @James Shape and Ranges have a Width and a Height properties. You can loop until the two roughly match.  `Target = `Range("$E$9:$AC$51")` .. `For h = 1 to Target.Rows.Count`.. `For w = 1 to Target.Columns.Count`..`If Target.Resize(h, w).Width = Shape.Width Then`